# Invalid conversion from int to main()::colors?

Tags: c

I'm new to C and I have been reading concepts and example code in a book titled "C Programming in easy steps".

So, I type in this example program, character for character:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    /* declare a sequence of constants */
    enum colors
    { RED=1,YELLOW,GREEN,BROWN,BLUE,PINK,BLACK };

    /* Declare a variable of the enumerated data type */

    enum colors fingers;

    /* assign valid constants from the colors list */
    /* -----THIS IS THE ERROR LINE BELOW---------- */

    fingers = (enum colors) PINK + BROWN;


    /*-display the value in the variable */
    printf("Value: %d\n", fingers);

    return 0;
}
```

and I get this error:

```
13 C:\Users\mjohearn\Documents\pet projects\constant types NOT WORKING\enumtypes.cpp invalid conversion from `int' to `main()::colors'
```

For some reason the compiler does not recognize `fingers`.

If anyone could help me solve this problem, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: oh, I can feel the answer tide incomming...

Comment: the file extension in C is ".c". ".cpp" is for C++. (You also want to use a C compiler, not a C++ compiler, to compile C).

Comment: PINK+BROWN=10 which is out of your list. Moreover, do you have to typecast PINK+BROWN?

Comment: Try using C compiler if you're compiling C code.  .cpp is the extension for C++ files.

Comment: This is C++ code (`main()` is illegal in C - needs to be `main(void)`). C++ does not allow operations on enums. Plus, remove the type cast, it makes no sense. Just use an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
fingers = (enum colors) ( PINK + BROWN ) ;
```

I believe the cast operator binds more tightly than the addition operator.

Comment: Right on! That did the trick. Is this because of new standards in "C" compilers? My text is dated 2002-2004.

Comment: Nope. Been that way since forever. Here's a C/C++ operator precedence chart -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence -- in descending order of priority and whether they are left- or right-associative. Plus...as @mingos pointed out, adding two enum values together doesn't really make any sense. If you want to learn C, get a copy of Kernighan & Ritchie's *The C Programming Language*, and then a copy of Harbison & Steele's *C: A Reference Manual*. K+R is one of the best (if not the best) programming texts ever written.

Comment: fwiw, gcc has no problems with OP's code; g++ gives the error message cited.